# R: consecutive occurrence of a number using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Some sample data firs:

```
  set.seed(123) 
  mat.1980 <- matrix(sample(0:1, replace = TRUE, size = 5L * 365L), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 5L) 
  set.seed(125) 
  mat.1981 <- matrix(sample(0:1, replace = TRUE, size = 5L * 365L), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 5L)
```

This is what I am trying to do:

`mat.1980` has five columns. Each column is a location and has 365 days of the year 1980 (365 rows) 
with values 1 or 0. `mat.1981` is the same data but for the year 1981 (next year).

I have another matrixt `mat1` (see below) which has certain days of the year for 1980 
for each column (location) in `mat.1980`.

```
  set.seed(123) 
  mat1 <- apply(matrix(sample(c(258:365), replace = TRUE, size = 4L * 5L), nrow = 4L), 2L, sort)
  mat1[4,5] <- NA
  mat1[3,3] <- 10
  mat1[4,3] <- 15
  mat1[4,4] <- 5

  head(mat1)


  # A tibble: 4 x 5
      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
  1   289   262   306   269   262
  2   302   315   307   319   284
  3   343   354    10   331   293
  4   353   359    15     5    NA
```

The days in each column are in ascending order for 1980. For example, in column 1 of `mat1`, 289 comes earlier than
302 and 302 comes earlier than 343. However, in column 3, 306 comes earlier than 307; 307 comes earlier than 10 (which is the 10th day of the 1981 i.e next year)
I need to use `mat1` to subset days in `mat.1980` to do a calculation. 
An example below:

1) For location 1 (first column in both `mat.1980` and `mat1`): In column 1 of `mat.1980`, 
      select the days from 289 till 302 (using `mat1`), find the longest consecutive occurrence 
      of 1. Repeat it and this time select the days from 303 (302 + 1) till 343 from `mat`, 
      find the longest consecutive occurrence of 1. Repeat it for 344 till 353: 
      select the days from 344 (343 + 1) till 353, find the longest consecutive occurrence of 1.

2) Do this for all the columns.

However the catch is: for location 3 (column 3 in `mat1`), since 10 and 15 comes in the next year 1981, this implies do step 1 using 10 additional days from `mat.1981`. An example:

For location 4 (fourth column in both `mat.1980` and `mat1`), to find the longest consecutive occurrence 
  of 1 for the period 308 till 10, concatenate day 308 till 365 from `mat.1980` and day 1 to day 10 from `mat.1981`
  and then find the longest consecutive occurrence of 1. Also if a value is NA, then insert NA

I am trying to use the rle function. Here's what I am trying to do.

```
library(tidyverse)

mat.1980 <- as.tibble(mat.1980)
mat.1981 <- as.tibble(mat.1981)
mat1 <- as.tibble(mat1)

pmap(list(mat.1980,mat.1981,mat1), ~ {
   range1 <- ..3[1]
   range2 <- ..3[2]
   range3 <- ..3[3]
   range4 <- ..3[4]
  c(range1=range1,range2=range2,range3=range3,range4=range4)
  })
```

This gives me the dates in a format suitable for my function.

Now subsetting days and doing an rle on them.

```
       fin.dat <- pmap(list(mat.1980,mat.1981,mat1), ~ {
         range1 <- ..3[1]
         range2 <- ..3[2]
         range3 <- ..3[3]
         range4 <- ..3[4]

        Val1 <- if(is.na(range1) | is.na(range2)) { # if either dates are NA, return NA
                 NA 
                } else if (range1 < range2) { # if first day comes earlier
                tapply(spell.range1$lengths, spell.range1$values, max)[2] <- 
                spell.range1 <- rle(..1[range1:range2])
                } else { # if second day comes in the next year
                tapply(spell.range1$lengths, spell.range1$values, max)[2] <- 
                spell.range1  <- rle(dat)  <- dat <- c(..1[range1:365])) , 
                (..2[1:range2]))}

      Val2 <- if(is.na(range2) | is.na(range3)) { 
               NA 
               } else if (range1 < range3) { 
               tapply(spell.range1$lengths, spell.range1$values, max)[2] <- 
               spell.range1 <- rle(..1[(range2+1):range3])
               } else {
               tapply(spell.range1$lengths, spell.range1$values, max)[2] <- 
               spell.range1  <- rle(dat)  <- dat <- c(..1[(range2+1):365])) 
                , (..2[1:range3]))}

        Val3 <- if(is.na(range3) | is.na(range4)) { 
                  NA 
                 } else if (range1 < range4) { 
                 tapply(spell.range1$lengths, spell.range1$values, max)[2] 
                 <- spell.range1 <- rle(..1[(range3+1):range4])
                 } else {
                 tapply(spell.range1$lengths, spell.range1$values, max)[2] 
                 <- spell.range1  <- rle(dat)  <- dat <- 
                 c(..1[(range3+1):365])) , (..2[1:range4]))}

            c(Val1 = Val1, Val2 = Val2, Val3 = Val3 )
   })
```

I get two errors:

```
Error: object 'Val1' not found
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

For some reason, I cannot use any other method and I need to apply the above code only. So it will be niceif someone can suggest me what I am doing wrong in the above code.

Comment: First, the second error clearly states that you have mis-matching expression closing braces. Second, I suggest you not use "repeated assignments" on line 14 of your big code block: though perfectly legal (and occasionally useful), it is confusing here, and I think you have an extra close-paren or two.